# PHP DOMDocument getting Attribute of Tag

Tags: php, parsing, dom, domdocument, xml-namespaces

Hello I have an api response in xml format with a series of items such as this:

```
<item>
<title>blah balh</title>
<pubDate>Tue, 20 Oct 2009 </pubDate>
<media:file  date="today" data="example text string"/>
</item>
```

I want to use DOMDocument to get the attribute "data" from the tag "media:file". My attempt below doesn't work:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('api response address');
foreach ($xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $feeditem) {
$nodes = $feeditem->getElementsByTagName('media:file');
$linkthumb = $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('data');
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

EDIT: I can't leave comments for some reason Mark. I get the error

```
 Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
```

when I run my code. I have also tried

```
$nodes = $feeditem->getElementsByTagNameNS('uri','file');
$linkthumb = $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('data');
```

where uri is the uri relating to the media name space(NS) but again the same problem.

Note that the media element is of the form  not   I think this is part of the problem, as I generally have no issue parsing for attibutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The example you provided should not generate an error. I tested it and $linkthumb contained the string "example text string" as expected

Ensure the *media* namespace is defined in the returned XML otherwise DOMDocument will error out.

If you are getting a specific error, please edit your post to include it

Edit:

Try the following code:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('api response address');
foreach ($xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $feeditem) {
    $nodes = $feeditem->getElementsByTagName('file');
    $linkthumb = $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('data');
    echo $linkthumb;
}
```

You may also want to look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) as it makes reading XML much easier than DOMDocument.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

```
$DOMNode -> attributes -> getNamedItem( 'MyAttribute' ) -> value;
```