# How to parse CDATA HTML-content of XML using SimpleXML?

Tags: php, html, xml, rss, simplexml

I am trying to display Xml content in to tables, all works perfectly but some content in the  tag that i don't want to display, I want only image but not

November 2012 calendar from 5.10 The Test

like in xml,

```
 <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>November 2012 calendar from 5.10 The Test</p>
    <p><a class="shutterset_" href='http://trance-gemini.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/calendars/laura-bertram-trance-gemini-145-1080.jpg' title='&lt;br&gt;November 2012 calendar from 5.10 The Test&lt;br&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;</a></p>]]>
</content:encoded>
```

I want to display image but not

November 2012 calendar from 5.10 The Test

.

```
<?php
// load SimpleXML
$item = new SimpleXMLElement('test1.xml', null, true);

echo <<<EOF
<table border="1px">
        <tr cl>

        </tr>       
EOF;
foreach($item->channel->item as $boo) // loop through our books
{
        echo <<<EOF

         <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">{$boo->children('content', true)->encoded}</td>
            <td>{$boo->title}</td>   
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>{$boo->description}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>{boo->comments}</td>
        </tr>
EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: "contents in thi tag that i dant eanto display" ??? A little more effort in writing a good question would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument getting Attribute of Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597746/php-domdocument-getting-attribute-of-tag) - you might not understand why I suggest this duplicate, please see my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15850774/367456

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [How to get an attribute with SimpleXML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3410520/367456)

Comment: Your question itself gave me a solution - using the proper reference for the <content:encoded> field. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I once answered it but I don't find the answer any longer.

If you take a look at the string (simplified/beautified):

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[
    <p>Lorem Ipsom</p>
    <p>
      <a href='laura-bertram-trance-gemini-145-1080.jpg' 
         title='&lt;br&gt;November 2012 calendar from 5.10 The Test&lt;br&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;</a>
    </p>]]>
</content:encoded>
```

You can see that you have HTML encoded *inside* the node-value of the `<content:encoded>` element. So first you need to obtain the HTML value, which you already do:

```
$html = $boo->children('content', true)->encoded;
```

Then you need to parse the HTML inside `$html`. With which libraries HTML parsing can be done with PHP is outlined in:

- [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456)

If you decide to use the more or less recommended `DOMDocument` for the job, you only need to get the attribute value of a certain element:

- [PHP DOMDocument getting Attribute of Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1597746/367456)

Or for its sister library SimpleXML you already use (so this is more recommended, see as well the next section):

- [How to get an attribute with SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3410520/367456)

---

> In context of your question here the following tip:

You're using SimpleXML. DOMDocument is a sister-library, meaning you can interchange between the two so you don't need to learn a full new library.

For example, you can use only the HTML parsing feature of `DOMDocument`, but import it then into `SimpleXML`. This is useful, because SimpleXML does not support HTML parsing.

That works via [`simplexml_import_dom()`](http://php.net/simplexml_import_dom).

A simplified step-by-step example:

```
// get the HTML string out of the feed:
$htmlString = $boo->children('content', true)->encoded;

// create DOMDocument for HTML parsing:
$htmlParser = new DOMDocument();

// load the HTML:
$htmlParser->loadHTML($htmlString);

// import it into simplexml:
$html = simplexml_import_dom($htmlParser);
```

Now you can use `$html` as a new SimpleXMLElement that represents the HTML document. As your HTML chunks did not have any `<body>` tags, according to the HTML specification, they are put inside the `<body>` tag. This will allow you for example to access the `href` attribute of the first `<a>` inside the second `<p>` element in your example:#

```
// access the element you're looking for:
$href = $html->body->p[1]->a['href'];
```

Here the full view from above ([Online Demo](http://eval.in/15171)):

```
// get the HTML string out of the feed:
$htmlString = $boo->children('content', true)->encoded;

// create DOMDocument for HTML parsing:
$htmlParser = new DOMDocument();

// your HTML gives parser warnings, keep them internal:
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// load the HTML:
$htmlParser->loadHTML($htmlString);

// import it into simplexml:
$html = simplexml_import_dom($htmlParser);

// access the element you're looking for:
$href = $html->body->p[1]->a['href'];

// output it
echo $href, "\n";
```

And what it outputs:

```
laura-bertram-trance-gemini-145-1080.jpg
```

Comment: I'd add just one thing: for sanity later, add an explicit `(string)` cast in `$htmlString = (string)$boo ...`  and `$href = (string)$html ...`. I find the mental overhead of always adding it when not needed is less than the overhead of debugging those cases where it was needed but you didn't realise.

Comment: @IMSoP: You never need it in something called string context in PHP. It's good to know about it even apart from SimpleXML alone. E.g. with `echo` it's always not necessary.

Comment: @hakre :this is work when i run on html file,but this code i applied  to in my php file i am getting error in-> notice: Undefined variable: htmlString in E:\Work Space\xampp\htdocs\Xml-Paser\note1.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined variable: htmlParser in E:\WorkSpace\xampp\htdocs\Xml-Paser\note1.php on line 30

Comment: @user2249819: Insert it at the right place in your file. As you can see with my example, I don't have any loop: http://eval.in/15171

Comment: @hakre Yes, I know. But like I said, I find it easier to always cast than remember which functions will do it automatically. Assigning to a variable can be especially problematic, as a non-string context call could happen dozens of lines later.

Comment: Sure, both ways are applicable. I normally don't care until I know I need string values. Then I can turn them into those. But the magic with SimpleXML is cause of many questions on SO, so it's good to educate this.

Comment: can any of write code fore me ,i am getting error ,which place i want to change?

Comment: @user2249819: Yes you can hire me for that.

Comment: ha ha ,dear i m a student of engg,not a developer ,ok i just want tu learn here ,

Comment: @ hakre if want to really help me as my teacher then please,other wise thanx to response me Sir.

Answer (score -3):

you would need to parse the image url eg via `preg_match` and this regex `'(http://(?:[^']*))'`

Comment: Thanx Vprimachenko,but can you tell me in which place i put this,can you give me one exemple or can you tell me in which place i have to change