# Parsing HTML tags from inside XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm trying to create my own RSS feed (learning purposes) using `simplexml_load_string` while parsing `http://uk.news.yahoo.com/rss` in PHP. I get stuck at reading the HTML tags inside the `<description>` tag.

My code so far looks like this:

```
$feed = file_get_contents('http://uk.news.yahoo.com/rss');
$rss = simplexml_load_string($feed);

//for each element in the feed
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo '<h3>'. $item->title . '</h3>'; 

        foreach($item->description as $desc){

             //how to read the href from the a tag???

             //this does not work at all
             $tags = $item->xpath('//a');
             foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                 echo $tag['href'];
             }
       }
}
```

Any ideas how to extract each HTML tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description content has its special characters encoded, so it's not treated as nodes within the XML, rather it's just a string. You can decode the special characters, then load the HTML into DOMDocument and do whatever you want to do. For example:

```
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo '<h3>'. $item->title . '</h3>'; 

        foreach($item->description as $desc){

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars_decode((string)$desc));

            $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
            echo $anchors->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
        }
}
```

XPath is also available for use with DOMDocument, see [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php).

Comment: Thank you. I turns out I was close but not close enough. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `<description>` element of the RSS feed contains HTML. Like as outlined in [How to parse CDATA HTML-content of XML using SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15849209/367456) you need to get the node-value of that element (the HTML) and parse it within an addtional parser.

The [accepted answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850774/367456) already shows this quite verbose, for SimpleXML it does not play much of a role here whether that RSS feed is using CDATA or just entities like in your case.

```
$feed = file_get_contents('http://uk.news.yahoo.com/rss');
$rss  = simplexml_load_string($feed);
$dom  = new DOMDocument(); // the HTML parser used for descriptions' HTML

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item)
{
    echo '<h3>' . $item->title . '</h3>', "\n";

    foreach ($item->description as $desc)
    {
        $dom->loadHTML($desc);

        $html = simplexml_import_dom($dom)->body;

        echo $html->p->a['href'], "\n";
    }
}
```

Exemplary output:

```
...
<h3>Chantal nears hurricane strength in Caribbean</h3>
http://uk.news.yahoo.com/chantal-nears-hurricane-strength-caribbean-220149771.html
<h3>Placido Domingo In Hospital With Blood Clot</h3>
http://uk.news.yahoo.com/placido-domingo-hospital-blood-clot-215427742.html
<h3>Berlusconi's final tax fraud appeal hearing set for July 30</h3>
http://uk.news.yahoo.com/berlusconis-final-tax-fraud-appeal-hearing-set-july-214714122.html
<h3>China: Men Rescued From River Amid Floods</h3>
http://uk.news.yahoo.com/china-men-rescued-river-amid-floods-213005159.html
<h3>Snowden has not yet accepted asylum in Venezuela - WikiLeaks</h3>
http://uk.news.yahoo.com/snowden-not-yet-accepted-asylum-venezuela-wikileaks-190332291.html
<h3>Three US kidnap victims break silence</h3>
http://uk.news.yahoo.com/three-us-kidnap-victims-release-thankyou-video-093832611.html
...
```

Hope this helps. Contrary to the accepted answer I see no reason to apply `htmlspecialchars_decode`, actually I'm pretty sure this breaks things. Also my example shows how you can stay inside the SimpleXML way of accessing the further children by showing how to turn the DOMNode back into a SimpleXMLElement once the HTML has been parsed.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. I like your answer as it give me back XML nodes. Thanks for taking the time to write it. Both answers helped me understand how to access these tags (values information). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is to use the var_dump() function on $item.

```
feed = file_get_contents('http://uk.news.yahoo.com/rss');
$rss = simplexml_load_string($feed);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
    exit;
}
```

Once you do that you'll see that the value you are after is called "link".  Therefore to print out the URL you will use the following code:

```
echo $item->link;
```

Comment: However, if I want to get only the description of the feed, this method does not work! As I'll get everything within the description tag (eg image)

Comment: Ah, that is because the actual "description" element in the RSS includes an image.  If you only want the text and not the image I would wrap the whole description with strip_tags function.  Therefore the code to print out *just* the description will be: echo strip_tags($item->description);

Comment: Cool. This works (as you said) just for the description (thx for this). But if I want to extract all elements with their attributes? Let's say in this case the `src` of the image? or maybe the `width` of the image?